# creating id's based on the line number

Tags: java

I'm working on a frame based application and I need to generate id's based on the calling site but really really fast.

To give a simple example to demonstrate the basics;

```
public void test() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    System.out.println(id());
  } else {
    System.out.println(id());
  }
}
```

Now `id()` should give a unique id, and when test is run again the id's should be the same. So counting is not possible.

A simple way to do that is using the line number, so the `id` method can look something like this (the index might have to be altered depending on how you call it):

```
int id() {
  return (new Throwable()).getStackTrace()[1].getLineNumber();
}
```

For robustness, in my current application I generate a id based on the whole stack. This makes nesting functions possible and still generate a unique consistent id. The problem is that it is slow, somewhere around `0.007ms` for one id. And for a file viewer for example, the id's a need to create can go into thousands.

Here is a example of what I do with it:
Toggle, slider, label and button have all a unique id that get's recreated every frame.

[image]
I also have been using a StackWalker, but the increase this gives is kinda disappointing. Does anyone have a idea of how to tackle this problem?

Comment: you could previously generate a (big)set of random UUIDs, and just iterate over it? Or some logic that generates them separately (another thread), on the fly, creating some kind of random-id-pool (controlling duplicates, etc.. based on your logic)

Comment: @AsierAranbarri I wan't to avoid keep track of logic cause that can really complicate things and make things more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

`Throwable.getStackTrace()` computes the whole stack trace elements. Try to call directly `Throwable.getStackTraceElement` by introspection. My benchmark tells it's almost 2 times faster. The difference should be greater if the stacktrace is bigger.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        StackTraceElement e = new Throwable().getStackTrace()[0];
    }

    // 2862
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);


    Method m = Throwable.class.getDeclaredMethod("getStackTraceElement", int.class);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        m.invoke(new Throwable(), 0);
    }

    // 1648
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);

}
```